# Oracle SQL WITH Clause : a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, with-clause

I want to use `with` clause in order to shorten column names which will be used for calculations

```
with Calc as(
SELECT entries.person_id,

MAX(DECODE(elements.element_name,'Basic Salary',values.screen_entry_value,0))/12 Salary,
MAX(DECODE(elements.element_name,'Mobile Allowance',values.screen_entry_value,0)) Mobile
FROM entries

JOIN values ON values.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = entries.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID
JOIN elements ON elements.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = entries.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID
JOIN value_types ON value_types.INPUT_VALUE_ID = values.INPUT_VALUE_ID
AND value_types.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = entries.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID

WHERE elements.language = 'US'
AND elements.element_name IN (
'Mobile Allowance',
'Transportation Allowance',
'Housing Allowance',
'Basic Salary'
)
AND value_types.base_name = 'Amount'

GROUP BY entries.person_id

)

select Salary, Mobile 

from persons 

JOIN Calc ON Calc.person_id = persons.person_id
```

whenever I add `with` clause block of code to my SQL query it gives error: `a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery`, I'm not even using outer join, what's the issue?

Comment: You have a table called `values`? This is not likely, because this is a SQL keyword. If the table is really called so, then you must use quotes (and know the correct upper/lower case spelling of the table name), e.g.  `JOIN "values" ON "values".ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = entries.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID`. (Well, if this is really the case, you should consider renaming this table to avoid any future problems.)

Comment: On a side note: it helps readability to use alias names for tables, e.g. `JOIN value_types vt ON vt.input_value_id = v.input_value_id AND vt.element_type_id = e.element_type_id`. The same is true for spelling consistency. I have used upper case for keywords here and lower case for table and column names. You are mixing them. Decide for a spelling pattern and follow that. (Keywords in upper case, names in lower case is very common. And with syntax highlighting available everywhere now, writing everything in lower case is also very common. Well, that's personal preference, but stay consistent.)

Comment: If you fix the invalid identifier `values` then I cannot replicate the problem [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8xLYaU8)

Comment: the table is not called value, i changed the name in the question to make it short

Comment: @aasemshoshari  please check this : 
select Calc.Salary, Calc.Mobile 
from persons p
JOIN Calc ON Calc.person_id = p.person_id

Comment: Did you change anything else? It would be better to post the *exact* query you're running, without any changes; along with the full error message/stack, the table definitions (maybe one is a view, and *that* has an outer join?), and your full Oracle version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't test anything (just corrected the code) - try it like this...

```sql
WITH 
    calc AS 
        (   Select 
                e.PERSON_ID,
                MAX(DECODE(elm.ELEMENT_NAME,'Basic Salary', v.SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE, 0)) / 12 "SALARY",
                MAX(DECODE(elm.ELEMENT_NAME,'Mobile Allowance', v.SCREEN_ENTRY_VALUE, 0)) "MOBILE"
            From 
                ENTRIES e
            Inner Join 
                VALUES_TABLE v ON(v.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = e.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID)      -- values is reserved word - check the spelling of your table name
            Inner Join 
                ELEMENTS elm ON(elm.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = e.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID)
            Inner Join 
                VALUE_TYPES vt ON(vt.INPUT_VALUE_ID = v.INPUT_VALUE_ID AND vt.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = e.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID)
            Where 
                elm.LANGUAGE = 'US' AND 
                elm.ELEMENT_NAME IN('Mobile Allowance', 'Transportation Allowance', 'Housing Allowance', 'Basic Salary') AND 
                vt.BASE_NAME = 'Amount'
            Group By e.PERSON_ID
        )
SELECT      SALARY, MOBILE 
FROM        PERSONS p
INNER JOIN  calc c ON(c.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID)
```